# Python 2.7.3 import functools gives me an AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'

Tags: python

I am stuck with an error that appears when I try to import functools. Here is the traceback:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import functools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/functools.py", line 72, in <module>
    globals()['c_%s' % x] = globals()[x] = getattr(_functools, x)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 66, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, urllib, re, pwd, grp, os
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    from functools import partial
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/functools.py", line 72, in <module>
    globals()['c_%s' % x] = globals()[x] = getattr(_functools, x)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/functools.py", line 72, in <module>
    globals()['c_%s' % x] = globals()[x] = getattr(_functools, x)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'
```

Any ideas? I am on Ubuntu 12.04 using python 2.7.3.

Comment: I found only this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871784/installing-functools-gives-me-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-c but I doubt it help you.

Comment: You have a package `functools` installed which is not the built-in `functools`. You need to remove it.

Comment: btw this question is not a duplicate as it is marked... I am getting the error when I am trying to import functools, I am not install it.

Comment: The `dist-packages` in the path reveals that this indeed is a duplicate of the other question - you have the `functools` pkg installed somehow. The path would **not** have `dist-packages` if the *builtin* `functools` module was imported.

Comment: @MartinTaleski: but the *cause is exactly the same*. You installed another functools package, and are importing *that*.

Comment: do you have a functools.py in your currentdirectory/sys.path? if so you have to remove it

Comment: The `functools.py` is in `dist-packages`. It most likely has been installed there by `pip`, `easy_install` or so. Try `sudo pip remove functools`

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I ended up manually removing functools and pip (as they were not working), and re-installing pip with apt-get.

Comment: Sorry, `sudo pip uninstall functools` is the command ofc.