# 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'

Tags: python

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871784/installing-functools-gives-me-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-c?rq=1), but I'm on a newer Ubuntu and `functools` is installed but isn't working properly.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, and whenever I try to do anything interesting in Python, it results in an error:

```
...something relevant to the actual application
...

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 17, in <module>
     import functools   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/functools.py", line 72, in
 <module>
     globals()['c_%s' % x] = globals()[x] = getattr(_functools, x) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compose'
```

This has been tried with `conjure-up`, `Robert` and some actual python code.
What can I do to fix it?

The relevant part of my `functools.py` looks like this:

```
try:
    import _functools
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    for x in __all__:
        globals()['c_%s' % x] = globals()[x] = getattr(_functools, x)
    del x
```

So, as I understand it, python tries to import `_functools`, fails and tries to launch some loop with `getattr` and that's where it fails to find some module attribute.

Comment: 17.04? We have february :P

Comment: Ok, read `16.04` then. I doubt that's really relevant; a guy in a related question had a similar issue with 12.04.

Comment: Can you install Python in a `virtualenv` and test that it works? What happened when you installed `functools`? Can you launch and interactive shell and import `functools` there, assuming it's installed and ready to go like the OQ indicated?

Comment: @nicorellius, probably "yes" and "yes", I'll report back with results.
Ok, the second one is a "no"; trying to `bpython` or `ipython` fails with the same error. Just `python` launches, but on `import functools` it fails similarly.

Comment: @nicorellius, ok, `virtualenv` failed as well: `in <module>
    @functools.wraps(_localeconv)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wraps'
`

Comment: Can you import anything at all from the shell? Are you willing to try another version of Python? In your OQ, you are referring to the system Python with this issue, right? Did you follow any of the recommendations in the other question you cited?

Comment: A really quick test has shown that I can `python` and then `import sys` and `import os`, but can't `import tensorflow`. I currently have both python2 and python3, if that's what you mean by different versions of python, but either way I'm ready to try something else. Also, sorry if this wasn't clear, but the question that's linked to in the top of this one is not from me, it's from someone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a few things to get rolling again... First, when I run into issues like this, I usually make sure I can run the commands in the shell:

```
user@host:~$ python
>>> import functools
>>> # then do some other stuff to convince yourself it's working
```

Also, install `virtualenv` (`virtualenvwrapper`) and and then create one for testing:

```
user@host:~$ mkvirtualenv venv
(venv) user@host:~$ python
>>>> # test here
```

Another thing to try is fetch another version of Python, say, version 3 (for an OS like Ubuntu):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get

Then create a `virtenv` with this version of Python:

```
user@host:~$ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6
```

It looks like your original installation of Python has some issues, and it might be hard to troubleshoot.

If this doesn't work, your primary Python might need to be repaired. If you are on Linux, having this problem can lead to other programs not functioning correctly.

If you think the installation of Python is broken or corrupt in some way, I might consider looking into reinstalling it, and there are several posts on SO that cover this.

Comment: Thanks. `import functools` from the python shell didn't work for me; `mkvirtualenv` encountered some other problems I won't go into now, and other programs on my system are already not functioning correctly, which is one of the reasons for my question :-)

Comment: I added a bit to my answer about reinstalling Python. Have you tried this yet? What OS are you on, BTW? Quick Google search turns up quit a few options for repairing Python.

Comment: Okay, I already have both python (2.7.13) and python3 (3.6.0). I regularly upgrade all the packages installed for both of them. My OS is Ubuntu 17.04, but that might sound confusing and I think we can consider it a 16.04. As for repairing python, I'd rather try to fix this one problem before googling for general python repair advice.

Comment: @Chiffa I'd love to help you, but this problem probably requires several troubleshooting steps, and adding more comments here might not help. If you already have Python2 and Python3, and both of these are giving you the same problem, then there is a systematic issue that you need to discover. Sometimes it's hard to fix broken libraries and packages, and it's easier to reinstall things. On top of that, I seem to have an incomplete picture of all your results from all the questions asked... So I'm not sure I can help unless we did chat or something...

Comment: Sorry, can this discussion be manually moved to chat? SO does this automatically after a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135726/discussion-between-chiffa-and-nicorellius).

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the context of the original question, but I wanted to point out that the `compose` function is in a different module: `functional`, not `functools`. This can be easy to miss if skimming through the Python [3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/howto/functional.html#the-functional-module) or [3.1](https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/functional.html#the-functional-module) functools documentation.

```
import functional

functional.compose(outer_fn, inner_fn)
```