# Pip install functools returns error

Tags: python, windows, pip, functools

I'm trying to install functools using pip. But i'm getting following error.

```
Collecting functools
  Using cached functools-0.5.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: functools
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for functools ... error
  Complete output from command c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\TAUSEE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-0gc470iw\\functools\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\TAUSEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpn0sob7vxpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
  copying functools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
  running build_ext
  building '_functools' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\python35\include -Ic:\python35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" /Tcsrc\functools.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\functools.obj
  functools.c
  src\functools.c(43): warning C4013: 'Py_InitModule3' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  src\functools.c(43): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
  src\functools.c(45): warning C4033: 'init_functools' must return a value
  src\functools.c(49): warning C4033: 'init_functools' must return a value
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\python35\include -Ic:\python35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" /Tcsrc\compose.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\compose.obj
  compose.c
  src\compose.c(57): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
  src\compose.c(96): error C2039: 'ob_type': is not a member of 'compose'
  src\compose.c(44): note: see declaration of 'compose'
  src\compose.c(137): warning C4013: 'PyString_FromFormat' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  src\compose.c(138): warning C4013: 'PyString_AsString' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  src\compose.c(138): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
  src\compose.c(143): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'Py_ssize_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [8]'
  src\compose.c(143): warning C4113: 'destructor' differs in parameter lists from 'printfunc'
  src\compose.c(143): warning C4133: 'initializing': incompatible types - from 'destructor' to 'printfunc'
  src\compose.c(143): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'PyNumberMethods *' differs in levels of indirection from 'reprfunc'
  src\compose.c(143): warning C4113: 'ternaryfunc' differs in parameter lists from 'reprfunc'
  src\compose.c(143): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'unsigned long'
  src\compose.c(143): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'traverseproc' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'
  src\compose.c(143): warning C4113: 'traverseproc' differs in parameter lists from 'inquiry'
  src\compose.c(143): warning C4113: 'PyObject *(__cdecl *)(PyObject *,PyObject *)' differs in parameter lists from 'descrsetfunc'
  src\compose.c(143): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'descrsetfunc' differs in levels of indirection from 'PyObject *(__cdecl *)(PyObject *,PyObject *)'
  src\compose.c(143): warning C4113: 'PyObject *(__cdecl *)(PyTypeObject *,PyObject *,PyObject *)' differs in parameter lists from 'freefunc'
  src\compose.c(143): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'freefunc' differs in levels of indirection from 'PyObject *(__cdecl *)(PyTypeObject *,PyObject *,PyObject *)'
  src\compose.c(143): warning C4133: 'initializing': incompatible types - from 'void (__cdecl *)(void *)' to 'inquiry'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for functools
  Running setup.py clean for functools
Failed to build functools
Installing collected packages: functools
  Running setup.py install for functools ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\TAUSEE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-0gc470iw\\functools\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\TAUSEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-z68u1oc7-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    copying functools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    running build_ext
    building '_functools' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\python35\include -Ic:\python35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" /Tcsrc\functools.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\functools.obj
    functools.c
    src\functools.c(43): warning C4013: 'Py_InitModule3' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    src\functools.c(43): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    src\functools.c(45): warning C4033: 'init_functools' must return a value
    src\functools.c(49): warning C4033: 'init_functools' must return a value
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\python35\include -Ic:\python35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" /Tcsrc\compose.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\compose.obj
    compose.c
    src\compose.c(57): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src\compose.c(96): error C2039: 'ob_type': is not a member of 'compose'
    src\compose.c(44): note: see declaration of 'compose'
    src\compose.c(137): warning C4013: 'PyString_FromFormat' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    src\compose.c(138): warning C4013: 'PyString_AsString' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    src\compose.c(138): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
    src\compose.c(143): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'Py_ssize_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [8]'
    src\compose.c(143): warning C4113: 'destructor' differs in parameter lists from 'printfunc'
    src\compose.c(143): warning C4133: 'initializing': incompatible types - from 'destructor' to 'printfunc'
    src\compose.c(143): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'PyNumberMethods *' differs in levels of indirection from 'reprfunc'
    src\compose.c(143): warning C4113: 'ternaryfunc' differs in parameter lists from 'reprfunc'
    src\compose.c(143): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'unsigned long'
    src\compose.c(143): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'traverseproc' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'
    src\compose.c(143): warning C4113: 'traverseproc' differs in parameter lists from 'inquiry'
    src\compose.c(143): warning C4113: 'PyObject *(__cdecl *)(PyObject *,PyObject *)' differs in parameter lists from 'descrsetfunc'
    src\compose.c(143): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'descrsetfunc' differs in levels of indirection from 'PyObject *(__cdecl *)(PyObject *,PyObject *)'
    src\compose.c(143): warning C4113: 'PyObject *(__cdecl *)(PyTypeObject *,PyObject *,PyObject *)' differs in parameter lists from 'freefunc'
    src\compose.c(143): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'freefunc' differs in levels of indirection from 'PyObject *(__cdecl *)(PyTypeObject *,PyObject *,PyObject *)'
    src\compose.c(143): warning C4133: 'initializing': incompatible types - from 'void (__cdecl *)(void *)' to 'inquiry'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I had this error before while installing resampy and I solved it by installing VS build tools. I also added vcvarsal.bat file to variable path and resampy was finally installed. But functools doesn't seem to install. Neither can I find wheel for it. I have pasted the entire message that I get after executing pip install functools

I'm using python 3.5.3
win10 x64

Would appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Doesn't functools come with Python? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871784/installing-functools-gives-me-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-c) answer suggests so

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The last update for the [functools on python package index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/functools) isfrom 2005. 
As [explained on this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871784/installing-functools-gives-me-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-c), it's been included into the standard library since python 2.7